# python またはGASを用いてGSSのデータを外部のhtmlフォームに自動入力をしたい

Tags: python, api, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

度々質問を申し訳ございません。
初心者質問です。
何列かのデータのGSSを自動的に連続して外部のフォームに入力、Ctrl+Sで保存、することは可能でしょうか？
方法は可能であれば、GASもしくはpythonでお教えいただけると幸いです。
(私としては、最終行までをlastrow()で取得し、forで繰り返す。
そして、fetch()でpostするのではないかと考えています。)

追記.1

> 何列かのデータのGSSを自動的に連続して外部のフォームに入力、Ctrl+Sで保存、することは可能でしょうか？

予定では、ブラウザ上で実行の予定です。

> Ctrl+S

ブラウザ上でのスプレッドシートの入力の項目を終了、保存する場合に保存ボタンをクリックするか、Ctrl+Sで保存できるので、Ctrl+Sの方が記述が容易だと考えたため、あのような文章になってしまいました。

> GASもしくはpython

私の方で調べたところ、自動で動かすプログラムで、私が理解できる言語が GASのものとpythonのものだったので、二つを書かせてもらいました。

---

下記、フォーム部分のコード

```
 <div id="main-content">
   <div id="action-area-top"></div>
       <div id="page-title">
       00003
       </div>
       <div id="breadcrumbs">
        <a href="/_gas-exp:start">Start</a> &raquo; 00003
       </div>
       <div id="page-content">
        <div style="display:none">
          <table class="form-table">
            <tr class="form-row">
             <td class="form-labels"></td>
             <td class="form-values">
              <div class="form-value field-content">
              <p>[ここに入力]</p>
              </div>
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </div>
         </div>
```

追記.2
APIを叩くことが出来るので、それで何かしらの方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: この機能の使われ方が上手く分からなかったのでどういう風なものなのかもう少し教えていただけませんでしょうか。特に Ctrl+S で保存というのが、何をどこに保存する話なのか分かりませんでした。Python と GAS では想定されている使用用途が違う気がするのですが、このプログラムはどこで実行されることを想定されていますか？（手元のローカル環境、サーバー、あるいはブラウザの上など）

Comment: 申し訳ございません。 言葉が足りておりませんでした。　　 ブラウザ上で実行の予定です。 ブラウザ上でのスプレッドシートの入力の項目を終了、保存する場合に 保存ボタンをクリックするか、Ctrl+Sで保存できるので、Ctrl+Sの方が記述が容易だと 考えたため、あのような文章になってしまいました。　　 私の方で調べたところ、自動で動かすプログラムで、私が理解できる言語が GASのものとpythonのものだったので、二つを書かせてもらいました。 @nekketsuuu

Comment: コメントで通知されると私にしか通知が来ないので、代わりに質問文を直接編集して追記するようにしてみてください。するとトップページの質問一覧で上に来るので複数の方の目に止まります :)